# Java: Having Multiple Components on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I want to have multiple components on a JFrame. I don't want any UI formatting. I just want multiple components to be drawn. My full code is to large to post so here is my JFrame set up.

```
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jPanel.add(board.getPieceAt(0,0));
    jPanel.add(board);

    frame.add(jPanel);
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

board and board.getPieceAt(0,0); are JComponents

No combination of frame.add() or adding panels seems to get both to render. It's always the last one added that gets drawn.

This example renders two components. I updated my code above to mimic this example as much as possible and it still results in an empty frame. To me it seems that I'm doing exactly what the example is doing yet I get a different result.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrameExample {

    public static void main(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a label!");

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Press me");

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

How do I get both components to render on the JFrame?

Comment: *"I don't want any UI formatting."*  If by 'UI formatting' you mean 'layouts' then the frame is currently using one, and the solution will lie in using a different one, or a combination of different layout managers. *"My full code is to large to post so here is my JFrame set up."*   1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: `frame.add(jPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);`, `frame.add(jPanelTwo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

Comment: I updated the post to include an example of what I wanted to achieve and my updated code following that example.

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.  *"updated the post to include an example.."*  I see a compilable code (2nd - a working MCVE) that you say is not the problem, and an uncompilable code snippet (which apparently is).  Post a broken MCVE if you want more help, and don't forget the drawing of what it is **supposed** to look like - otherwise we can only guess.